# What focal length does Lee Jeffries use for his portraits?

Tags: portrait, focal-length

I'm astonished by the portraits of an English photographer, Lee Jeffries.

Does anybody knows the focal length he shoots with?

[The link to his flicker.](https://www.flickr.com/photos/16536699@N07/)

Answer (score 4):

Poking around a little leads to [his 500px account](https://500px.com/LeeJeffries) where metadata is present. It looks like he typically shoots a Canon 5D with a 24mm or 85mm lens.

Comment: Which two (just for interest's sake) also represent a *huge* fraction of Joe McNally's portrait work. (I'd upvote, Dan, but this account can't do that.)